# Make lowercase equal to capital letters in R

Tags: r, string, compare, case-insensitive

I need to check if 2 strings are the same between 2 tables. The problem is that the table 1 is in lowercase and the table 2 in capital letters. I need to make this function in **R** so it has to give a TRUE value for example in this case:

```
    "this is a string" == "THIS IS A STRING"
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: You can use `toupper` or `tolower`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the `stri_cmp_equiv()` function from the `stringi` package for that. It tests for canonical equivalence of two strings and is locale-dependent. Additionally, the ICU's Collator may be tuned up so that e.g. the comparison is case-insensitive.

```
library(stringi)
stri_cmp_equiv("this is a string", "THIS IS A STRING", strength=2)
## [1] TRUE
stri_cmp_equiv("hladn\u00FD", "hladny", strength=1, locale="sk_SK") # hladný
## [1] TRUE
stri_cmp_equiv(stri_trans_nfkd("\u0105"), "\u105") # "ą"
## [1] TRUE
stri_cmp_equiv("\ufb00", "ff", strength=2) # "ﬀ"
## [1] TRUE
stri_cmp_equiv("G\u00e4rtner", "Gaertner", locale="de_DE@collation=phonebook", strength=1L) # "Gärtner"
## [1] TRUE
```

Or, if it is a too heavy machinery for your needs, you may - as @docendodiscimus suggested, test whether

```
tolower("a string") == tolower("A STRING")
## [1] TRUE
```